# Как реагируют поисковики на знак # в URL?

Tags: url

Есть ли проблемы в индексации таких адресов? Что дает использование восклицательного знака после #?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочесть «[Сканирование AJAX. Руководство для разработчиков и веб-мастеров](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20150418122806/https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992?hl=ru)».